# Displaying .json map in D3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I did a tutorial on displaying a map in d3 with the world-50m.json file. However I wish to use my own json file. this is the structure of my .json file.

"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{ "type": "Feature","properties": { "FID": 0.000000 }, "geometry": { "type":"MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[[[141.415967, -15.837696 ]....and the coordinates go on.

However the call in the code is for the old world-50m.json and yes I do realise that at the moment the code is referencing the world-50m.json I will change that to my file:

data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.countries)

My Question is what call do I use for my new .json file. I have tried heaps of combinations but keep getting the error topology.objects is undefined.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>



path {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 0.25px;
    fill: grey;
}


</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/topojson/topojson.js"></script>
<script>


var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
    .center([-30, -17 ])
    .scale(3000)
    .rotate([-180,0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

// load and display the World
d3.json("json/world-50m.json", function(error, topology) {
    g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.countries)
            .features)
    .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)

    d3.csv("data/CairnsPort2012.csv", function(error, data) {
        g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return projection([d.LONG, d.LAT])[0];
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return projection([d.LONG, d.LAT])[1];
            })
            .attr("r", 0.1)
            .style("fill", "red");
    }); 

});

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function() {
        g.attr("transform","translate("+
            d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        g.selectAll("path")
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
});

svg.call(zoom)


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, first we need to sort out the order of your call to load the map data.

We need to put the error call second like so.

```
d3.json("json/world-50m.json", function(topology, error) {
```

Then I think you need to change the following;

```
g.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.countries)
        .features)
```

... to ...

```
g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topology.features)
```

I say that this may work based on a working map I have here that has a very similar json layout

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[
    {
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties":{"name":"New Zealand","iso_a2":"NZ","iso_a3":"NZL","iso_n3":"554"},
    "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[ [ [ [ 167.44947350400005, -47.23943450299987 ], ....and the coordinates go on ] ] ] ]}}
  ]
}
```

... and the following code.

```
var g = svg.append("g");

d3.json("json/nz-10m2.json", function (topology, error) {
  g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topology.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

Comment: Ok, so I made the fixes, as above comments. First I was face with the error typeerror: topology is null.  I though this may be because error and topology were switched, so I tried function(error, topology) and I no longer had any errors in the console, however my map was not displaying, I was just faced with a blank page. Any ideas?

Comment: Update: It seemed to work with function(error, topology). Not sure why, maybe you know more than me here.

But no map was displaying(it was fetching the map fine). Created a new map from a .shp using ogr2ogr. And it worked fine. Thanks for the help d3noob. I have learnt a lot in a short amount of time, appreciated.

Comment: Great news. Interesting about the error and topology swapping. I have a version here that requires the other way around. Strange. Well done on working through it.

Comment: I am using d3.v3.min.js, what are you using, I was thinking maybe it has something to do with a particular version of d3, I know d3.v3 is different from d3.v3.min. But yeah it was definitely those order that was making topology null.

Comment: You're spot on. I was actually using d3.v2 for the graph. When I changed to d3.v3 it threw an error (whatever way topology and error was put) and when I changed to d3.v3.min I had to have the order error, topology! Don't quite know what to make of that. I suspect it might be something to do with my geojson file, but I don't have the energy to chase it.